# Opening Task module from Adaptive Card using Action.OpenUrl

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

we are posting an Adaptive card in channel using following **Graph API** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs

Our payload is

```json
{
  "body":{
    "contentType":"html",
    "content":"<attachment id="attachmentId"></attachment>"  // for attachmentId see attachments section below
  },
  "attachments":[
    {
      "id":"attachmentId",
      "content":cardData // this is JSON.stringify of actual Adaptive card data 
    }
  ]
}
```

Also our Adaptive card is like

```json
{
  "type":"AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "body":"some body",
  "actions":[
    {
       "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
       "title":"Suggest Item",
       "url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/2a05d07c-d194-400e-8122-cad64cfe1cef?url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44349%2Fteams%2F%23%2Fsuggest%2Fee31b3aa-f60f-4594-a964-a01fcc461ceb%3Ffrom%3Dcard&height=540&width=800&title=*Suggest%20item"
    }
  ]
}
```

If i post task module Url in chat and click it works,
But it is not working from **Adaptive Card** `Action.OpenUrl`
Previously it used to work

Comment: there was a `*` in my url so link was'nt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a `*` in my url for title, after removing that it works again

Answer (score 2):

Task module deep link works fine from Adaptive card OpenUrl. Could you please try following JSON payload?

```
{
             "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "<attachment id=\"fa74618d23064677a1af25d0ae973532\"></attachment>"
            },
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "fa74618d23064677a1af25d0ae973532",
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    "content": "{\r\n    \"type\": \"AdaptiveCard\",\r\n    \"actions\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"type\": \"Action.OpenUrl\",\r\n            \"title\": \"View\",\r\n            \"url\": \"https:\/\/teams.microsoft.com\/l\/task\/f195eed2-4336-4c33-a11b-a417dcaa8680?url=https:\/\/taskmoduletest.azurewebsites.net\/customform&height=430&width=510&title=Custom%20Form&fallbackUrl=https:\/\/taskmoduletest.azurewebsites.net\/customform\"\r\n        }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"$schema\": \"http:\/\/adaptivecards.io\/schemas\/adaptive-card.json\",\r\n    \"version\": \"1.0\"\r\n}"
                }
            ]
}
```

Please let us know if you are facing any issues.